# What is the best way to extend a Magento model behaviour?

Tags: magento2

If I wanted to change the function getPrice for instance? **[Edit]** Lets suppose that I wanted to change the way that the price is calculated. e.g.: if the customer is from a certain state, the price should be multiplied by 1.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to change would be using `Plugins(Interceptors)`

There are three types of `plugins`:

- before
- around
- after

You can read more about here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html